# Using Singleton Design Pattern for AWS Library

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-layers

I am creating an AWS Client Library for myself, to use in AWS Lambda.
Storing them in Lambda Layers

AWS: 
-DynamoDBAdapter.js 
 -APIGatewayWebsocketAdapter.js 
 -S3Adapter.js 
 -SecretManagerAdapter.js

And using them in my lambda functions:

```
const DynamoDBAdapter = require("/opt/aws/DynamoDBAdapter.js")
```

Is creating these classes as Singleton would be a good idea for optimization? So that I don't initialize in the constructor multiple clients for the aws services (using the aws sdk v3), or will it cause throttling of a process at high requests?

Tried searching online if there was any answer to that.

Comment: Lambda Layers are simply a packaging/sharing construct for code. There's no shared runtime state between one Lambda function invocation and another concurrent invocation using the same layer.

Comment: @jarmod So if I have 2 lambda functions pointing to the same lambda layer, each one will get its own version? Basically creating a singleton is specific to each lambda invocation ? If yes, then the same lambda can be used by multiple users, so the question holds.

Comment: Typically you would create session objects and other similar things like database connections in the [global scope](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/global-scope.html) i.e. outside of the handler function so that they can be re-used for subsequent warm starts. A given Lambda function invocation will never experience [concurrent](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-aws-lambda-function-concurrency/) use. Any reuse of an execution environment will be sequential (called "warm start").

Comment: So, no, creating a singleton is not specific to each Lambda invocation . It's specific to each Lambda execution environment (which may experience multiple invocations).

Comment: So it does make sense sometimes to create Singleton right? Let's say with DynamoDB, instead of each multiple invocations creating its own connection to dynamodb, importing the singleton class will make them all share the same instance. (by all meaning the multiple invocations)

Well the question here is, is it efficient to do that? or can it cause throttling down the line ?

Comment: Yes, it's sensible to do [static initialization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/static-initialization.html). Resources created are reusable across subsequent invocations of the same Lambda execution environment, and they're also cheaper and faster because the init phase has more CPU and zero cost. It will likely reduce the number of outbound connections overall. Note that downstream API throttling (e.g. by the DynamoDB service) is going to depend on how fast you are making requests, so that's a different issue.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you. So basically using a Singleton approach will make the multiple invocations use the same client instance, thus optimizing. But if there are many requests in a short period of time, throttling can be caused since all the invocations in the same lambda layers are using the same instance. So for my case, there number of requests will not be close to the API rate limits, therefore a singleton would optimize instead of throttle. Right ?

Comment: Forget about Lambda Layers here. They're just a convenient packaging construct and have no substantial contribution to the discussion on API throttling or connection reuse. I'd recommend a deeper read of [Lambda execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html).

Comment: @jarmod I meant to write 'same lambda function'

Comment: Using the singleton approach doesn't necessarily make multiple invocations of the Lambda function use the same client instance. If you trigger 500 invocations of your Lambda function simultaneously, for example, and you have sufficient configured concurrency then the Lambda service could create 500 execution environments, hence no client reuse. But if the Lambda service can reuse prior execution environments (because they've completed the processing of prior requests) then you'll get client reuse.

Comment: @jarmod Okay I see. So it totally depends on my use case: How many configured concurrency I have, and the # of requests that will be going through the lambda, along with the timeframe of that.

Which leaves me to the conclusion to use a Singleton approach, since it will, at least, optimize when the environment is being reused.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of @jarmod

> Using the singleton approach doesn't necessarily make multiple
> invocations of the Lambda function use the same client instance. If
> you trigger 500 invocations of your Lambda function simultaneously,
> for example, and you have sufficient configured concurrency then the
> Lambda service could create 500 execution environments, hence no
> client reuse. But if the Lambda service can reuse prior execution
> environments (because they've completed the processing of prior
> requests) then you'll get client reuse

One should balance the concurrency settings with the volume of requests they have. Static Initialization (or Singleton design pattern as to the constructor) will optimize when the execution environment is being reused. Whether that could throttle depends on the service used, your configuration, their rate limits and the volume of requests.